# How does MergereRecord processor calculate a Bin size in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

#### requirements:

When I want to merge through Mergerecord, with the Bin size as the restriction, and use PutPqrquet to write to HDFS in Snappy compression, so that the size of the written Parquet file is the same as the Bin size.

#### My approach:

1. Split

I used SplitRecord after reading the existing data, breaking the records into streams every 10, in order to keep the merge unit smaller. The Processor is written in AvroRecordSetWriter and in the Snappy compressed format.

[image: SplitRecord]

[image: AvroRecordSetWriter]

2. Merge

I used Mergerecord to merge and split the stream files, AvroReader and AvroRecordsetWriter, selected the bin-packing algorithm, set the maximum Bin number as 1, the minimum Record number as 1, the maximum Record number as 100000000, the maximum Bin size as 1024MB, the minimum Bin size as 1000MB, and the Max Bin Age as 1 day.

According to the actual data and the rules of the BIN algorithm, the data will be automatically merged when it reaches 1024MB. When 1024MB is not reached, it will also automatically merge after a day.

[image: MergeRecord]

3. Write the HDFS

Use PutParquet to select AvroReader, Snappy Compress, Row Group Size 1GB

[image: PutParquet]

#### The actual write condition:

During the merge process, I found that each stream file was 1GB, but the Parquet file written to HDFS was only around 950MB, not 1000-1024MB.

[image: HDFS files]

#### Ask questions:

[image: Nifi canvas]

What rules does Mergerecord use to calculate Bin sizes? I initially thought I was calculating the size of the data written by AvroRecordSetWriter, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can someone tell me?

Comment: did you check this? - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeRecord/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Hello, @VikramsinhShinde. I have read it, and according to the Bin packing algorithm rule, my Processor will merge when the Maximum Bin Size is reached, but I have not found out how the Processor calculates to reach the Max Size. Calculate the size of the data in FlowFile Repository or the size of the data written by AvroRecordSetWriter?

Comment: You might find some useful info in source code of `MergeRecord` processor - 
https://github.com/cttestid41/Apache_nifi/blob/67819e5019893fc02022a5d361759b3504276753/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/MergeRecord.java

Comment: Thanks for your information, @VikramsinhShinde I read the source code through the IDE, found the logic of Bin MAX_SIZE judged by Margerecord, and saw how it loaded the Controller Service. I came to the conclusion that the Bin size calculated in Mergerecord is calculated in the previous Avro format, and the final format written to HDFS is Parquet. So I don't get the results I want. According to the actual situation, using the same Schema, Avro format files are indeed larger than Parquet format. Thanks again for your help.